# Trying to update JSON in Postgres table but getting an unknown error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

This is the query I'm trying...

```
UPDATE users 
SET preferences = jsonb_set(preferences, '{some_key}', 'true'::jsonb) 
WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

But I keep getting the error that the second argument to `jsonb_set` is unknown and it's unclear why that is the case. The string key definitely exists. `some_key` is a key in `preferences` (the column name in the table).

Anyone know what might be causing this?

These queries work...

```
SELECT preferences -> 'some_key' AS some_key FROM users

SELECT preferences -> 'some_key' AS some_key FROM users WHERE preferences -> 'some_key' = 'false'
```

**UPDATE**

This is an example of what the `preferences` column contains...

```
“some_key”=>"false", "some_other_key"=>"true",
```

Comment: The query is OK, there must be a problem elsewhere. Show table definition and sample data in such a way that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Not sure if's enough but I added what one would expect to see in the column `preferences`

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid jsonb in the preferences column.

Comment: hmm...not sure what you mean but trying to check. my selects work so confusing that the update doesnt

Comment: What is the type of your column `preferences` ? Did you use type `jsonb` or `json` ? Because that could be the reason.

Comment: Ah I'm checking as I'm not sure but the data type that postgresql shows is `hstore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it...

`UPDATE user SET preferences = preferences || '"some_key"=>"true"' :: hstore;`

Need to use the right data type

Comment: Thanks! That works. I just assumed it was json either way and used what I've found online